# Connecting to postgresql from python 3, running in Cloud Shell: password authentication failed

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I try to run locally (from GCP terminal) **python 3** tutorial program to connect to my **postgresql** dsatabase.

I run proxy, as it is suggested in source:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=xxxxxxxx:us-central1:testpg=tcp:5432
```

it works, I can connect to it with:

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 sslmode=disable dbname=guestbook user=postgres
```

Unfortunately when I try to connect from python:

```
   cnx = psycopg2.connect(dbname=db_name, user=db_user,
                           password=db_password, host=host)
```

host is 121.0.0.1 -as I run it locally, I get this error:
*psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"*

I can't get around what I miss?
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) to manage your connections and best of all you won't need to worry about running the proxy manually. It supports the `pg8000` postgresql driver and can run from Cloud Shell.

Here is an example code snippet showing how to use it:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector
import sqlalchemy

# configure Cloud SQL Python Connector properties
def getconn() ->:
    conn = connector.connect(
        "xxxxxxxx:us-central1:testpg",
        "pg8000",
        user="YOUR_USER",
        password="YOUR_PASSWORD",
        db="YOUR_DB"
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool to re-use connections
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# query or insert into Cloud SQL database
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

For more detailed examples refer to the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) of the repository.